# chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener unexpectedly opens tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, runtime

This is about chrome extensions.

I placed the following piece of code to open a tab when the extension has been installed:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (object) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://myurl.com/?installed=yes"}, function (tab) {});
});
```

Shame on me for not testing it exhaustively, but to be fair this is quite new to me and up to now it worked reliably so i forgot about it.

But now some users tell me they experience unexpected behaviour in that the tab is opened without the extension having been updated, deactivated or anything else. They just start the browser and it pops up... Yet i have not been able to reproduce the problem, hence i am asking if some of you guys have experienced alike incidents and if you could point me to what's wrong and/or where i can learn a little more about...

(1st question, add to that my engrish might not be the best, don't be offended... i try :D )

Comment: This is a [Chrome bug](https://crbug.com/303481), see the link for a workaround code. I haven't tested it, so see if it works and add it as an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you wOxxOm for pointing me to that page!

Although the workaround didn't exactly fit (i only want to show the page on first time install), i managed to scribble the following out of it:

```
var manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details){
    var prevVersion = localStorage.getItem('previousVersion');
    if (prevVersion == null){
        chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://myurl.com/?installed=yes"}, function (tab) {});
        localStorage.setItem('previousVersion', manifest.version);
    }
});
```

What do i do here... I check a storage variable which is not present on first time install and will ONLY THEN create a tab. When the tab is created i set the storage, so that next time it will not ever fire up again...

Hopefully this will work out... so Thank you very much!!